# Laravel - how to create (anonymous) Dynamic Blade Components in Views

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-7

Using Laravel 7 with the newly added blade components--

I have some dynamic fields that are returning an array. Inside the array contains each "component" stored as "layout", I have a component that is named exactly after the component class. In my base view, I'm looping through the array and rendering the component:

```php
@if ($page->content)
    //@dd($page->content):
    {{-- array:1 [▼
        0 => {#425 ▼
            +"layout": "wysiwyg"
            +"key": "W0yC0KtNgPV8N4ua"
            +"attributes": {#1303 ▼
            +"alignment": "default"
            +"background_color": "default"
            +"text": "<h1>Hello World</h1>"
            }
        }
        ] --}}
    @foreach ($page->content as $content)
        <x-{{ $content->layout }} :content="$content"/>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

However, this renders nothing (it's blank). The source of the compiled blade shows `<x-wysiwyg :component="$content"/>` so it's acting like it's not compiling at all. However, If I update my foreach loop component content explicitly: `<x-wysiwyg :content="$content"/>`, it works and renders the component.

How can I dynamically load components with values?

Comment: I think this will be an issue with the order that Laravel parses the blade template. If you enter the old style layout @include does it work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This actually isn't possible in Laravel 7 but coming soon to Laravel 8:

https://twitter.com/taylorotwell/status/1265681297286082562

```php
<x-dynamic-component :component="$componentName" class="mt-4" />
```

Edit: Now released - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#dynamic-components

Comment: Does this work with anonymous components?

Comment: @EugenevanderMerwe Yes, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#dynamic-components

Comment: Thanks so much. I struggled when my components were in a subdirectory but when I moved them to the root of the components folder it worked.